# Python Pulp linear programming with dynamic constraint

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

I currently use Solver in excel to find somewhat optimal solution for manufacturing. Here is the current setup:
[image]

It regards manufacturing shoes on a rotary machine, that is, production is done in batches of repetitions. For example one batch would be '10x A1' (see A1 in table) which would yield 10x size 36, 20x size 37... 10x size 41.

There are some prefixed setups; A1, A2; R7... as you see in the table above.

Then there is the `requested` variable (or rather a list of variables) that basically says what the customer requested, quantities per size.

The **objective function** is to find a set of repetitions such that it matches requested quantities as closely as possible. Hence in the solver (sorry for non-English screenshot) you can see the goal is `N21` (that is the sum of absolute differences per size). The variables are `N2:N9` - that's the repetitions per setup and the only constraint is that `N2:N9` is an integer.

How can I model this behaviour with python? My start:

```
from collections import namedtuple

from pulp import *


class Setup(namedtuple('IAmReallyLazy', 'name ' + ' '.join(f's{s}' for s in range(36, 47)))):
    # inits with name and sizes 's36', 's37'... 's46'
    repetitions = 0


setups = [
    Setup('A1', 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    Setup('A2', 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    Setup('R7', 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    Setup('D1', 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    # and others
]

setup_names = [s.name for s in setups]

requested = {
    's36': 100,
    's37': 250,
    's38': 300,
    's39': 450,
    's40': 450,
    's41': 250,
    's42': 200,
}


def get_quantity_per_size(size: str) -> int:
    return sum([getattr(setup, size) * setup.repetitions for setup in setups])


def get_abs_diff(size: str) -> int:
    requested_size = requested.get(size, 0)
    return abs(get_quantity_per_size(size) - requested_size)


problem = LpProblem('Optimize Batches', LpMinimize)
# goal is to minimise the sum(get_abs_diff(f's{size}') for size in range(36, 47))
# variables are [setup.repetitions for setup in setups]
# constraints are all([isinstance(setup.repetitions, int) for setup in setups])
```

*In an ideal world* if there is more than one optimal solution, the one with most spread abs diff should be selected (ie. the one with the smallest highest difference). That is, if one solution has abs diff of 10 per size and 10 sizes (total 100) and other has 20 + 80 = 100, the first one is more optimal for customer.

Another constraint should be `min(setup.repetitions for setup in setups if setup.repetitions > 0) > 9` basically the repetitions constraint should be:

- Is integer
- Is either 0 *or* greater than 9 - This is not possible in linear programming from what I've understood so far though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things here. First, if you use `abs()` then the problem will be nonlinear. Instead, you should introduce new variables called, say, `over_mfg` and `under_mfg`, that represent the number of units produced *above* of the target and the number *below* the target, respectively. You can declare these like this:

```
over_mfg = LpVariable.dicts("over_mfg", sizes, 0, None, LpInteger)
under_mfg = LpVariable.dicts("under_mfg", sizes, 0, None, LpInteger)
```

I declared a list called `sizes`, which is used in the definitions above:

```
min_size = 36
max_size = 46
sizes = ['s' + str(s) for s in range(min_size, max_size+1)]
```

You also need variables indicating the repetitions of each setup:

```
repetitions = LpVariable.dicts("repetitions", setup_names, 0, None, LpInteger)
```

Your objective function is then declared as:

```
problem += lpSum([over_mfg[size] + under_mfg[size] for size in sizes])
```

(Note that in `pulp` you use `lpSum` rather than `sum`.) Now, you need constraints that say that `over_mfg` is the excess and `under_mfg` is the shortfall:

```
for size in sizes:
    problem += over_mfg[size] >= lpSum([repetitions[setup.name] * getattr(setup, size) for setup in setups]) - requested[size], "DefineOverMfg" + size
    problem += under_mfg[size] >= requested[size] - lpSum([repetitions[setup.name] * getattr(setup, size) for setup in setups]), "DefineUnderMfg" + size
```

Note also that I didn't use your `get_quantity_per_size()` and `get_abs_diff()` functions. These will also confuse `pulp` since it won't realize that these are simple linear functions.

Here is my complete code:

```
from collections import namedtuple

from pulp import *


class Setup(namedtuple('IAmReallyLazy', 'name ' + ' '.join(f's{s}' for s in range(36, 47)))):
    # inits with name and sizes 's36', 's37'... 's46'
    repetitions = 0


setups = [
    Setup('A1', 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    Setup('A2', 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    Setup('R7', 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    Setup('D1', 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    # and others
]

setup_names = [s.name for s in setups]

min_size = 36
max_size = 46
sizes = ['s' + str(s) for s in range(min_size, max_size+1)]

requested = {
    's36': 100,
    's37': 250,
    's38': 300,
    's39': 450,
    's40': 450,
    's41': 250,
    's42': 200,
    's43': 0,    # I added these for completeness
    's44': 0,
    's45': 0,
    's46': 0
}

problem = LpProblem('Optimize Batches', LpMinimize)
# goal is to minimise the sum(get_abs_diff(f's{size}') for size in range(36, 47))
# variables are [setup.repetitions for setup in setups]
# constraints are all([isinstance(setup.repetitions, int) for setup in setups])

repetitions = LpVariable.dicts("repetitions", setup_names, 0, None, LpInteger)
over_mfg = LpVariable.dicts("over_mfg", sizes, 0, None, LpInteger)
under_mfg = LpVariable.dicts("under_mfg", sizes, 0, None, LpInteger)

problem += lpSum([over_mfg[size] + under_mfg[size] for size in sizes])

for size in sizes:
    problem += over_mfg[size] >= lpSum([repetitions[setup.name] * getattr(setup, size) for setup in setups]) - requested[size], "DefineOverMfg" + size
    problem += under_mfg[size] >= requested[size] - lpSum([repetitions[setup.name] * getattr(setup, size) for setup in setups]), "DefineUnderMfg" + size

# Solve problem
problem.solve()

# Print status
print("Status:", LpStatus[problem.status])

# Print optimal values of decision variables
for v in problem.variables():
    if v.varValue is not None and v.varValue > 0:
        print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

Here is the output:

```
Status: Optimal
over_mfg_s38 = 62.0
over_mfg_s41 = 62.0
repetitions_A1 = 25.0
repetitions_A2 = 88.0
repetitions_D1 = 110.0
repetitions_R7 = 1.0
under_mfg_s36 = 75.0
under_mfg_s37 = 2.0
under_mfg_s40 = 25.0
```

So, we manufacture 25 repetitions of A1, 88 of A2, and 110 of D1, and 1 of R7. This gives 25 units of `s36` (hence 75 units under the target of 100); 248 units of `s37` (2 under target); 362 units of `s38` (62 units over the target of 300); and so on.

---

Now, for your constraint that says you *either* have to produce 0 of a setup *or* >9, you can introduce new binary variables indicating whether each setup is produced:

```
is_produced = LpVariable.dicts("is_produced", setup_names, 0, 1, LpInteger)
```

Then add these constraints:

```
M = 1000
min_reps = 9
for s in setup_names:
    problem += M * is_produced[s] >= repetitions[s] # if it's produced at all, must set is_produced = 1
    problem += min_reps * (1 - is_produced[s]) + repetitions[s] >= min_reps
```

`M` is a big number; it should be bigger than the largest possible number of repetitions, but no bigger. And I defined `min_reps` to avoid "hard-coding" the 9 in the constraints. So, these constraints say that (1) if `repetitions[s] > 0`, then `is_produced[s]` must equal 1, and (2) *either* `is_produced[s]` = 1 *or* `repetitions[s]` > 9.

The output:

```
Status: Optimal
is_produced_A1 = 1.0
is_produced_A2 = 1.0
is_produced_D1 = 1.0
over_mfg_s38 = 63.0
over_mfg_s39 = 1.0
over_mfg_s41 = 63.0
repetitions_A1 = 25.0
repetitions_A2 = 88.0
repetitions_D1 = 112.0
under_mfg_s36 = 75.0
under_mfg_s40 = 24.0
```

Note that now we don't have any setups with >0 but <9 repetitions.

---

> In an ideal world if there is more than one optimal solution, the one with most spread abs diff should be selected (ie. the one with the smallest highest difference).

This one is trickier, and (at least for now), I'll leave this to an ideal world, or another person's answer.

---

*By the way*: There is an effort to launch a [Stack Exchange site for Operations Research](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121892/operations-research-and-analytics), where we'll be all over questions like this one. If you're interested, I encourage you to click the link and "commit".

Comment: Thank you @LarrySnyder610 - I've made a small app based on it, see here: https://youtu.be/0qXo1QCPkvc - it works beautifully.

Comment: One more thing if I may - how would you go about restricting the maximum number of setups allowed? That is, I want to use for example "maximum 3 different setups". I assume the `is_produced_<name>` can be reused but how would the constraint look like?

Comment: nevermind, got it, `problem += lpSum([is_produced[s] for s in setup_names]) <= max_setups` =)